# Play! Framework: Please annotate your JPA model

Tags: java, playframework

My class Import, is like that:

```
package models;    

import java.util.Date;    
import javax.persistence.Entity;  
import play.db.jpa.Model;    
import play.mvc.Scope.Session;    
import constantes.CommonConstants;    

@javax.persistence.Entity    
public class ImportCSV extends Model {    

    public ImportCSV() {    
        if (null != Session.current()) {    
            this.CreatedBy = Session.current().get(CommonConstants.SESS_ID_UO_LOGIN);    
            this.uoSite = Session.current().get(CommonConstants.SESS_ID_UO_SITE);    
            this.uoRealm = Session.current().get(CommonConstants.SESS_ID_UO_REALM);    
        }       
    }      

    public String dataType;  
    public String csvFileName; 
    public String fileStatus;  
    public Date CreateAt;    
    public String CreatedBy; 
    public String uoSite;    
    public String uoRealm;    
    public Date LoadedAt;   
    public String realmImporte;  
    public String siteImporte; 

}
```

But, when I try to do `ImportCSV.findById(34);`, the code does no further in Play! 1.4.4.

I tried to monitor this line in debug mode under Eclipse, and it throws

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.
    at play.db.jpa.JPASupport.findById(JPASupport.java:385)
    at jobs.ImportCSVJob.onException(ImportCSVJob.java:92)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:127)
```

Comment: Are you sure your annotation is `@javax.persistence.Entity` and is not from hibernate?

Comment: As you can see in the imports, it uses javax.persistence.Entity

Comment: sorry, did not notice.

Comment: I tried to directly put @javax.persistence.Entity same result

Comment: Can you show your complete `ImportCSV`?

Comment: I edited the original post.

Comment: Sorry, no clue...

Comment: Is it possible that you have not correctly configured a JDBC datasource?